# Can we use the parameters of FOREACH inside the activities of IF condition in azure data factory

Tags: if-statement, foreach, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

**How to use foreach activity parameters inside the if activity which is inside foreach**
i passed the values to the if condition like if true it will perform an activity but if false it had to use the values of the failed condition. but in the false condition i had to copy the false activity filenames to other location  but in the filename option how to get parameters which are passed from the foreach activity

Comment: You will not be able to use foreach inside if condition. Instead, use the foreach inside a child pipeline and call that pipeline using execute pipeline activity inside if condition

Comment: Also please post more details about the requirement. It's unclear. Kindly Post the pipeline activities and it's settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually to get the current item in the iteration, you use `item()` in dynamic expression under `ForEach iterator` section in `Add dynamic content` tab

[image]

However, when you try to find it inside an activity i.e. past 2nd level of hierarchy

It is not listed!

[image]

### Workaround:

Just inside of `Foreach` activity, use **set variable** activity to store the **current item** in iteration to a variable. Then **reference** this variable in further activities.

### Example:

Simple `ForEach activity` with input array `param`

[image]

[image]

`IfCondition` activity inside `ForEach` activity. Assign **current item** to a **variable** `var` of type **String**

[image]

For case `true` it performs some activity eg: `wait`

[image]

For case `false` it performs a copy activity

Query: `Select * from Persons where city = '@{variables('var')}'`

[image]

[image]

Comment: This only works if the foreach loop runs sequentially. Otherwise the variable will get changed by parallel iterations.

Comment: I also looking for the solution that will work with parallel execution